# How to calculate expected value given its probability?

Tags: probability

I am weak in Math and was stuck on this problem:

> A project has the following risks: 20% probability of a 14-day delay
>   in the receipt of customer requirements; 10% probability of a 21-day
>   delay in the procurement process; 50% probability the integration will
>   take 14 days longer. What is the expected time value of these events?
>
> A. 11.9 days
>
> B. 35.8 days
>
> C. 49 days
>
> D. Seven days

Can someone please guide me on how I can solve it?

Comment: Hint: $E[X+Y+Z]=E[X]+E[Y]+E[Z]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Conceptually*, expected value is an average value, weighted by its various probabilities. *Computationally*, this ends up being* a sum of [values $\times$ probabilities of being those values]. So, if we call the receipt delay by $R$, then $R$ is either $14$ or $0$, and it is those things with probabilities $0.2$ and $0.8$, respectively; hence,
$$\mathbb E[R] = 14 \cdot 0.2 + 0 \cdot 0.8 = 2.8.$$
Similarly, you can compute the expected procurement delay ($P$) and integration delay ($I$). As @JMoravitz noted, the total delay is $\mathbb E[P + R + I] = \mathbb E[P] + \mathbb E[R] + \mathbb E[I]$. Can you take it from here?

*Note: this is true for discrete variables such as the type encountered here, but not true for all random variables. If you had something like a normally-distributed variable, then it doesn't assume particular values at all, and this formulation of its expected value doesn't make much sense. If that comment made no sense to you, don't worry about it; it may be a technicality that's beyond what you need to consider.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand from your explanation `E[R]=14⋅0.2+0⋅0.8=2.8.`. The answer is 11.9 days.